# Quickly finding rows that contain a value with specific substring requirements

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data frame that is 40 columns wide and 3 million long. Each cell can contain a value, or is missing. Each row has at least a few cells filled. I am interested in finding those ROWS that contain any value starting with "M" and having a '3' as the sixth character. My biggest issue is how to handle this given the size of the data frame...

```
n=40*300000 # 300k already takes long, let alone 3M!
data <- data.frame(matrix(paste0(sample(LETTERS, n, replace=T), sample(c(10000:99999), n, replace=T)), ncol=40))
```

The following code will find all the codes starting with M and having a '3' at the end, however, it is slow... and then I also need to have a vector returned that shows me which row contains any of the codes of interest (1) and which not (0).

```
data[sapply(data, substring, 1, 1) == "M" & is.na(data)==F & sapply(data, substring, 6, 6) == "3" ]
```

My main issue is that I need a speedy solution!

Comment: Use `data.table` and for speedy solution try `Rcpp` package.

Comment: You could do this sapply(data, substr, c(1,5), c(2,6))=='M3' in a single call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startsWith` and `endsWith` are faster than `substring`, and each `sapply` is a loop, which will take a while. (If you need `sapply` but need speed, check out `vapply`.)

Here, we can use `apply` to evaluate each row for `any` matching elements where `df` is the original data.frame (`data` is a bad name that can cause conflicts). Rows with `NA`s and matching values will return `TRUE`; rows with `NA`s but no matching values will return `NA`. If you'd rather have `FALSE`, wrap `x` below in `na.omit`.

```
# takes 7 seconds on my machine
row_indices <- apply(df, 1, function(x){any(startsWith(x, 'M') & endsWith(x, '3'))})

head(row_indices)
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

# effectively instantaneous
df_subset <- df[row_indices, ]

df_subset[1, ]
##       X1     X2     X3     X4     X5     X6     X7     X8     X9    X10    X11    X12    X13
## 5 Q69164 D42439 X17664 A81746 Z82859 B10892 I39329 O29425 D83560 W14944 M64225 K47156 X26742
##      X14    X15    X16    X17    X18    X19    X20    X21    X22    X23    X24    X25    X26
## 5 I51962 Q57501 Q29214 W20713 U84761 S35597 D93796 F15041 V51597 O93538 O55946 F67256 D85638
##      X27    X28    X29    X30    X31    X32    X33    X34    X35    X36    X37    X38    X39
## 5 N82913 Q55887 V10815 M59412 L17626 E83108 E40069 I21677 U99952 X24291 O55932 M79693 C48984
##      X40
## 5 O63422
```

`row_indices` is a logical vector with `TRUE` for each row that satisfies the conditions, and `FALSE` otherwise. If you want it as a vector of 1s and 0s, coerce to integer:

```
row_indices_integer <- as.integer(row_indices)

head(row_indices_integer)
## [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Bonus: If you want an index of matches, a faster way is to convert to a matrix, which you can index as a giant vector. Both coercing and subsetting takes about 3 seconds on my machine.

```
df_m <- as.matrix(df)    # make sure you have enough memory

matches <- df_m[startsWith(df_m, 'M') & endsWith(df_m, '3')]

head(matches)
## [1] "M67343" "M73753" "M61813" "M67903" "M25393" "M64273"
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't vouch for "*quickly*", but this is hopefully reasonably fast.

Leave the data as a matrix, then apply a `grepl` over it searching for the pattern once. Your subset has multiple conditions that are searched independently, which significantly increases processing time. Rather, a `regex` search only passes over the matrix once. Here I'll use just the first three `LETTERS` so the results are clear:

```r
## simple example
set.seed(1337)
n=40L*30L

## leave the data as a matrix
data <- matrix(paste0(sample(LETTERS[1:3], n, replace=T), sample(c(10000:99999), n, replace=T)), ncol=40)
head(data)
#>      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]    
#> [1,] "B38741" "C40838" "C55778" "C68287" "A75243" "C78612" "C97148"
#> [2,] "B74071" "A96422" "A32523" "B24202" "C37424" "A43132" "C22392"
#> [3,] "A59076" "C46817" "C60189" "C45901" "B21047" "A37862" "A11632"
#> [4,] "B46388" "A58535" "C97558" "B40380" "B68486" "A47478" "B79243"
#> [5,] "B43385" "C94160" "A61546" "C57602" "C56007" "B79242" "B87491"
#> [6,] "A21263" "B16484" "A97093" "B85175" "A81363" "C11184" "A55769"
#>      [,8]     [,9]     [,10]    [,11]    [,12]    [,13]    [,14]   
#> [1,] "A60364" "B40600" "B47028" "A91703" "A29644" "C18189" "C27397"
#> [2,] "A79862" "C14384" "A76795" "C56399" "C17494" "A97131" "B93359"
#> [3,] "A71215" "B11017" "C28779" "A93073" "B41637" "B22438" "B71168"
#> [4,] "C93900" "B16089" "C11622" "B47537" "A59246" "A70339" "B50932"
#> [5,] "C49844" "A47108" "C25245" "C13744" "A33516" "B74005" "B66537"
#> [6,] "C18771" "A19343" "C80973" "B43260" "A34422" "C93295" "B78965"
#>      [,15]    [,16]    [,17]    [,18]    [,19]    [,20]    [,21]   
#> [1,] "A11028" "B56979" "A82965" "B22924" "A41345" "A87897" "C50275"
#> [2,] "B94595" "C57700" "C52641" "A20425" "A71739" "B68890" "B41689"
#> [3,] "A81026" "C96270" "A25976" "B58948" "A90145" "A46911" "A91987"
#> [4,] "B67972" "A67499" "A25004" "A82919" "A65356" "B68767" "C14904"
#> [5,] "A63617" "A51983" "C23317" "C89821" "B34018" "A14499" "A52000"
#> [6,] "B72869" "B29073" "C44628" "A49682" "B40933" "B63931" "B33618"
#>      [,22]    [,23]    [,24]    [,25]    [,26]    [,27]    [,28]   
#> [1,] "C71020" "C25807" "C71922" "C54801" "B71390" "C46267" "A21002"
#> [2,] "A95403" "B10427" "C60669" "B28275" "C27129" "A73589" "C51430"
#> [3,] "C82188" "A49040" "A47890" "C50170" "C46741" "A80651" "C96004"
#> [4,] "A71968" "B54081" "C11767" "A79653" "C56663" "A34188" "B69740"
#> [5,] "A95088" "B22995" "C41531" "B29874" "B28097" "A51224" "B31888"
#> [6,] "B80639" "A45005" "C18228" "C96166" "A68540" "C12882" "C87778"
#>      [,29]    [,30]    [,31]    [,32]    [,33]    [,34]    [,35]   
#> [1,] "A12776" "C37308" "A42790" "C72401" "A35752" "B89962" "C83482"
#> [2,] "B78347" "C64552" "C18353" "B93191" "C75289" "C67916" "B67485"
#> [3,] "A70870" "A80181" "C82050" "B82481" "A49520" "C23423" "C70112"
#> [4,] "A32132" "A14885" "C98653" "C26822" "A60790" "C23231" "C71949"
#> [5,] "B60348" "C44937" "C31036" "A90012" "C81055" "C13806" "A13882"
#> [6,] "C91144" "C90857" "A14201" "B61155" "C43489" "B31109" "B83677"
#>      [,36]    [,37]    [,38]    [,39]    [,40]   
#> [1,] "A56118" "C84724" "C80238" "C22425" "B93431"
#> [2,] "C76893" "C16722" "A95319" "B54856" "B36155"
#> [3,] "C35688" "C39321" "A37359" "B26495" "A88542"
#> [4,] "B65839" "A65305" "C56256" "C11397" "B11289"
#> [5,] "A73778" "A69947" "A98016" "A40535" "B38351"
#> [6,] "B18384" "C61695" "B56768" "C39147" "C27065"
```

Extracting the elements (don't extract them if you want a matrix of `TRUE/FALSE` in the original dimensions)

```
## find elements which start with "A" and end with "3"
data[grepl("^A.*3$", data)]
#>  [1] "A21263" "A32523" "A97093" "A75243" "A81363" "A12483" "A25883"
#>  [8] "A71073" "A19343" "A46733" "A91703" "A93073" "A80463" "A97873"
#> [15] "A87763" "A17953" "A91103" "A88293" "A47273" "A32483" "A68723"
#> [22] "A51983" "A91283" "A75353" "A71283" "A91793" "A75253" "A95403"
#> [29] "A73373" "A64863" "A74823" "A80853" "A41883" "A79653" "A97783"
#> [36] "A96793" "A57573" "A77983" "A93863" "A25783" "A20173" "A25313"
#> [43] "A53833" "A17933"
```

I've recently fallen in love with `rex` for building `regex` and while this is a simple search, it's more readable with `R` syntax:

```
## alternatively, using the power of rex
data[grepl(rex::rex(start, "A", anything, "3", end), data)]
#>  [1] "A21263" "A32523" "A97093" "A75243" "A81363" "A12483" "A25883"
#>  [8] "A71073" "A19343" "A46733" "A91703" "A93073" "A80463" "A97873"
#> [15] "A87763" "A17953" "A91103" "A88293" "A47273" "A32483" "A68723"
#> [22] "A51983" "A91283" "A75353" "A71283" "A91793" "A75253" "A95403"
#> [29] "A73373" "A64863" "A74823" "A80853" "A41883" "A79653" "A97783"
#> [36] "A96793" "A57573" "A77983" "A93863" "A25783" "A20173" "A25313"
#> [43] "A53833" "A17933"
```